# The library is compiled without QT support in function error when running Python virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, opencv, python-venv

I was trying to run this installed library - https://github.com/alkasm/magicwand but when I tried to run a command in the commmand line "python -m magicwand C:\Users\home\Pictures\img.png", it returned this error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\home\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\magicwand\__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
    window.show()
  File "C:\Users\home\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\magicwand\__init__.py", line 84, in show
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\home\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\magicwand\__init__.py", line 80, in _update
    cv.displayStatusBar(self.name, ", ".join((meanstr, stdstr)))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:567: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) The library is compiled without QT support in function 'cv::displayStatusBar'
```

I checked for solutions to the problem but I couldn't find one. I also have already installed opencv-python through pip.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Installing `opencv` from **conda** fixed this problem for me:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```